# Box2d contact listener collision

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I am trying to realize one way platform using Box2d. This is my code:

```
public void preSolve(Contact contact, Manifold oldManifold) {
    Fixture platform = null;
    Fixture ranger = null;

    Fixture fa = contact.getFixtureA();
    Fixture fb = contact.getFixtureB();

    if (BodyUtils.isPlatform(fa.getBody()) && BodyUtils.isRanger(fb.getBody())) {
        platform = fa;
        ranger = fb;
    } else if (BodyUtils.isPlatform(fb.getBody()) && BodyUtils.isRanger(fa.getBody())) {
        platform = fb;
        ranger = fa;
    }

    if (platform == null) return;
    Body platformBody = platform.getBody();
    Body rangerBody = ranger.getBody();

    int rangerTopY = (int) (rangerBody.getPosition().y + ((RangerUserData)rangerBody.getUserData()).getHeight() - 0.5f);
    int platformBottomY = (int) platformBody.getPosition().y;
    if (rangerTopY == platformBottomY) {
        contact.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

The problem is that `contact.setEnabled(false)` called but not working. Why is so?

Comment: Did you debug your code? And in _which way_ isn't it working?

Comment: @Thomas, yes. Well, when my `Ranger` collides with the `Platform` then called `contact.setEnabled(false)` and `endContact` method is immediately called in which I do `contact.setEnabled(true)`. Maybe this is the problem? Then why is `endContact` method called immediately?

Comment: When I made a one way platform I made all the platforms sensors. Then whenever a body was in the sensor I negated all downward velocity. This allowed objects to go up through them but not down.

Comment: @Thomas, I noticed another thing: in `preSolve` I set enabled to false, but in `beginContact` enabled is true, why is so?

Comment: I'm no expert on Box2D but it seems that `preSolve()` is called _after_ `beginContact()` so why shouldn't `enabled` be true there?